# Why wasn't The Matrix built with perfect physics?

Tags: the-matrix

Physics experienced in The Matrix wasn't perfect. There are many examples, but only one is in my mind at this time: In the end of the first movie, when helicoper crashed to the building, building produced ripples like water. It could be a big trouble if a physicist (or, anyone with little IQ) would have seen it (Machines never wanted that people would realize the truth, according to Animatrix).

By not rendering realistic explosion, were machines saving processing power at a cost of healthy batteries?

Comment: The scene with the helicopter occurs as Neo is really starting to flex his powers as "The One". I always understood it as the distorted physics being Neo's doing. In fact, Tank sees this and immediately comments that "He's The One. He's got to be." Morpheus and Neo then discuss Neo's realization.

Comment: @phantom42 That's exactly what it was supposed to be.  It's extremely similar to the later scene when Neo fully realizes his potential and literally flexes his muscles as he exhales deeply and the environment around him ripples with his power.

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar - Can you provide a scientific reference showing that a building with glass windows could not produce ripples like that if a helicopter crashed into it?

Comment: I think we need to take this to Mythbusters.

Comment: Also, IIRC, that scene was in slo-mo. Things really do ripple in slo-mo. I'd have to watch it again to be sure, but I'm almost positive that's slo-mo.

Comment: @sachinShekhar - I think you need to think this question through a bit more, I don't think you've done any research before posting it (not that we aren't all guilty of that every now and then). I suggest a bit of rewording and expansion.

Comment: To Close-votes: Which part of the question are you unable to understand?

Comment: @SachinShekhar I think your whole premise is faulty. Mostly in that I'm not sure that the 'physics' displayed in the movies is so out of whack that even a casual observer would notice something wrong.

Comment: Assuming the physics portrayed *are* inaccurate, I would reason it's more likely just to be over or poor usage usage of special effects (depending on your point of view) than a relevant plot point. For example, in movies where cars do unrealistic things is it more likely to be to look cool/unintentionally unrealistic or that the movie is happening in an alternate dimension where such things are possible?

Answer (score 10):

Let's look at the scene in context. [From the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Matrix,-The.html):

> **NEO**
>
> Oh fuck.
>
> Trinity throws the helicopter towards the roof of the
>   nearest building.
>
> Morpheus and Neo cling to one another as they and the
>   machine above them begin to fall.
>
> The ENGINE GRINDS, the CHOPPING BLADES start to slow
>   while --
>
> The Agents stand in the open shattered window, watching
>   the helicopter disappear behind taller buildings.
>
> Carried by its nomentum, Trinity guides the parabolic
>   fall over the nearest roof where --
>
> Neo and Morpheus drop safely, rolling free as the rope
>   goes slack.  Neo gets to his feet, trying to detach
>   himself but --
>
> The helicopter is falling too fast, arcing over the roof
>   like a setting sun --
>
> The coils of slack snap taught --
>
> Yanking Neo off his feet, dragging him with ferocious
>   speed towards the edge even as --
>
> Trinity lunges for the back door, her gun in one hand,
>   grabbing for the rope with the other --
>
> Neo flies like a skipping stone, hurtling straight AT us,
>   when his feet hit the rain gutter --
>
> A fulcrum that levers him up just as --
>
> Trinity FIRES, severing the cord from the HELICOPTER,
>   falling free of it as it SMASHES, blades first into a 
>   glass skyscraper.
>
> Holding onto the rope she swings, connected to Neo, who
>   stands on the building's edge watching her arc beneath
>   him as the HELICOPTER EXPLODES --
>
> She bounces against a shatterproof window that spider-
>   cracks out while FLAMES ERUPT behind her.
>
> INT.  MAIN DECK
>
> Tank stares at the screen, his mouth agape.
>
> **TANK**
>
> He's the One.  He's got to be...
>
> EXT.  ROOFTOP (MATRIX) - DAY
>
> Neo pulls Trinity up into his arms.  Both shaking, they
>   hold each other again.
>
> **MORPHEUS**
>
> I knew it!  I goddamn knew it!
>
> **TRINITY**
>
> Morpheus!
>
> She runs at him, throwing her arms around him.
>
> **MORPHEUS**
>
> Do you believe me now?  He's the
>   One!  Who else could have done
>   this?

By this scene, Neo is coming to accept his role as *The One*. He has already started doing some incredible things during the rescue of Morpheus. It's when Trinity's life put in imminent danger that he really steps up and flexes his powers. As viewers, we see this as the ripple effect that you describe.

While the script itself glosses over it, it has always been my understanding that Neo bends reality to protect Trinity (along with Morpheus and himself). This is supported by the responses by Tank and Morpheus immediately afterwards.

So, physics *were* simulated "perfectly", it's just that Neo decided to bend them in this instance.

Comment: To note, prior to this, all major events occur more or less how we would expect them to. The building the truck runs into does not ripple for example. Also- not just Neo is messing with things, a lot of agents and "free-men" are involved, and possibly helping to ruin the simulation.

Comment: Tank said "He's the One. He's got to be..." because Neo saved the day. Also, he didn't have powers to bend reality at that time.

Comment: He's *always* had the powers, he just didn't believe he had them. His whole journey in the movie is him coming to accept the fact that he *is* "The One".

Comment: @phantom42 Ok. Whatever... he didn't realize that much at that time. Otherwise, he would smash Agents very badly in the first encounter after that event (instead of being shot).

Comment: He's using them without knowing it to save the woman he loves. Tank realizes this. Morpheus notices. And even if he does believe it now, it's not like he will instantly know how to do everything as "The one".

Answer (score 3):

I can think of 2 possible answers:

1- How would you know that that's not exactly how explosions look, if all the things you know of reality are controlled by the same entity that renders the explosion that way?

Or

2- I'll bet that it was simply rendered like that to make it look "cooler" to the eyes of the viewers (us).

Comment: Weren't vehicle collisions, explosions etc perfect? Researchers can't digest it.

Comment: Why wouldn't reaserchers accept whatever information was given to them? If everything they have known was based on what they learned while living in the Matrix than it's easy to assume that there would be no reason to not believe that everything they see is perfectly normal.