# Were there non-AI physicists and scientists in the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31560/why-wasnt-the-matrix-built-with-perfect-physics) question made me wonder- were there non-AI physicists and scientists in the Matrix?  Or anyone of tested superior intelligence (thus, potentially disruptive to maintaining illusion of reality)?

Comment: I'm a physicist (retired) and I'm not an AI - at least, I don't think so ...

Comment: @JohnRennie But are you in the Matrix?

Comment: @MrLister: aren't we all? :-)

Comment: There are power stations and building sites so there must be engineers at least

Comment: "In reality, there is no such thing as an [exact science](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Exact_science)." – William Stanley Jevons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I can't recall any direct evidence of physicists or other scientists there are some highly intelligent hackers who come to realise that there is 'something wrong'  with their world.

> Morpheus: I know *exactly* what you mean. Let me tell you why you're here. You're here because you know something. What you know you can't explain, but you feel it. You've felt it your entire life, that there's something wrong with the world. You don't know what it is, but it's there, like a splinter in your mind, driving you mad. It is this feeling that has brought you to me. Do you know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

### Scientists:

In the Matrix comic [Let it All Fall Down](http://web.archive.org/web/20040614034339/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/paul_fallmain.html) we meet Peter Schoppe, a [Computer Scientist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_scientist). His invention (interrogative programs known as EPOs) cause precisely the sort of malfunction that you've described, allowing him to view the exterior of the Matrix.

[image]

---

In [System Freeze](http://web.archive.org/web/20040806135534/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/popp_z.html) we meet Fria Canning, an [AI researcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence).

> "Die deep in the ice then, if you like. It makes very little
>   difference to me either way. But I'm not the Devil, or any other such
>   silly human bogeyman, and all I want from you is something you would
>   have done anyway."
>
> "What?" she managed to spit out.
>
> "Finish the new AI program you began work on before you left for
>   Nepal.
>
> We will contact you when it's completed, and we will pay you very
>   handsomely for it."

---

In the Matrix Comic [A Path Among the Stones](http://web.archive.org/web/20040603105425/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/gregr01.html) we encounter Dr. Frey, a psychologist and yes, psychology is a science, I checked.

[image]

There don't seem to be any *physical* scientists inside the Matrix for obvious reasons.